# Pfsense 2.3.3 site to site via openvpn wierd issue with routing

Tags: networking, openvpn, pfsense

I have followed this guide : https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/OpenVPN_Site_To_Site, youtube videos and anything else I can find through google but this issue is baffeling me. I have a site to site link with pfsense using openvpn. the link is up and heres the wierd part. any client on either side can ping both its own gateway, and the lan ip of the other router, but not client to client across the link.

router 1 lan 172.16.0.254/24
router 2 lan 172.16.1.254/24

a client on the 172.16.0.0/24 can ping BOTH 172.16.0.254 AND 172.16.1.254
a client on the 172.16.1.0/24 can ping BOTH 172.16.1.254 AND 172.16.0.254

but a client on 172.16.1.0/24 cannot ping another client on the 172.16.0.0/24 network except for a couple of linux machines where I do route add -net 172.16.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 172.16.0.254.

now I'm not sure what I'm missing but with a site to site tun with openvpn I should't be having to do that. the youtube videos I've watched none of them modified routing tables, openvpn did it all so I'm at a loss here

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

ok aparently I need more sleep its actually working, the linux ones aren't using dhcp is why i had to add the static route and the windows machines its a windows firewall issue, disabling windows firewall temp the pings went through, so this question can be deleted.